# According to the Jehovah’s Witnesses, if Jesus Christ is not God why is He presented as the agent of creation?

Tags: christology, gospel-of-john, creation, jehovahs-witnesses, colossians

John 1:3, "All things came into being by Him, and apart from Him (or without Him) NOTHING came into being that has come into being." Also Colossians 1:16-17, "For by Him all things were created, in the heavens and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities--all things have been created by Him and for Him."

Verse 17, "And He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together." I would also include Hebrews 1:10 spoken by God the Father, "And, Thou, Lord in the beginning didst lay the foundation of the earth, And the heavens are the works of Thy hands."

The verses quoted are all encompassing and "ALL" things came into being by Him/Jesus Christ, and apart or without Him "NOTHING" came into being. So what are these "other" things that "a god" (NWT of John 1:1) the Jehovah Witnesses are referring to at Colossians 1:16? Why is the word "other" added to the verse?

Comment: Whose perspective exactly are you asking about?

Comment: You might want to read further because John1:18 speaks Jesus eternally existed in the "bosom of the Father". https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21237/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-the-bosom-of-the-father-john-118

Comment: Could you flesh out this question a bit more? In your mind, what is the relationship between these scriptures and the topic of whether Jesus is God?

Comment: @NigelJ Not so, I am not stating my own argument. I posted Biblical verses that clearly identify Jesus Christ as God the creator.  I am asking the Jehovah Witnesses to "RECONCILE" their position that Jesus Christ is "a god" from their own NWT Bible at John 1:1 to "RECONCILE" it to Colossians 1:16. Why did they add the word "other" in the verse and what are these "other" things Jesus created as "a god?" And no, I am not asking people to "attack" the argument. I am asking them (the JW's) to explain the contradiction, that's the point Nigel.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Well, yes, they can do that from their translation, of course. But not from the original Greek.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/75762/23657.  Related on the use of the word “other”

Comment: Hi Kris. I read the site you posted and will respond to it in due time. I would like your "personal" opinion on Colossians  1:16 in regards to the NWT adding the word "other?" Like I posted in this thread, what are these "other" things that are not included in what was already created in the first place?

Comment: @Mr. Bond - "Personal" opinions are not acceptable on Christianity Stack.  You have asked for an explanation from Jehovah's Witness and therefore that means ONLY the official J.W. view (in explanation of the contradiction) is allowed with regard to your question. If they do not see a contradiction, then they must explain why they do not see a contradiction.  Nobody else's "opinion" matters.

Comment: Okay Lesley, got it, and thanks!

Comment: I'm still unclear on what the question is asking. Jehovah's Witnesses believe that God first created his Son, Jesus, and then God used his Son to create everything else. So all things (except Jesus himself) were created by God through Jesus. I'm not sure if that's what your question is asking for. I can write a formal answer that expounds on it if that's the answer you're looking for

Comment: 4castle Isaiah 44:24 says God created ALL things by Himself and all alone. The Jw's say Jesus is a created being himself and is "a god" according to John 1:1 (NWT). John 1:3 says all things have been created by this "a god." Colossians 1:16-17 says "For by Him all OTHER things were created." They use the word "other" four times. I'm asking what are these "other" things Jesus created since God said He created everything "all alone" and "by Himself? The word "other" is not in the Greek text, it's been added by them. So how do the JW's reconcile using "other" with the Biblical text without other?

Comment: See my answer to another of your questions here https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/75314/23657

Comment: Related: [How do Jehovah's Witnesses differentiate Jesus' role in creation from that of a Demiurge?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/75850/32540)

Comment: You are really asking at least two questions here both have been asked before as indicated in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Jehovah’s Witnesses explain the unique wording of Colossians 1:15-17 in the NWT?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75762/how-do-jehovah-s-witnesses-explain-the-unique-wording-of-colossians-115-17-in-t)

Answer (score 2):

Once it is understood that the word "other" is added five times by the NWT Committee to their rendering of Colossians 1:16-20, but NOT even once to John 1:1, that will give a fairer representation of their view that Jesus is an agent of creation. Also, to keep matters clear, it needs to be pointed out that they do believe Christ is deity in the sense of being "a god" (only one that must not be worshipped as the Father is worshipped).

***The question is based upon why Christ is presented as the agent of creation, by Jehovah's Witnnesses.*** Again, for clarity, it should be pointed out that they speak of him as the MAIN agent of creation, but that the Father created Christ first, so that the Father is the initiating agent of creation, choosing to then use this one, whom they also call Michael the Archangel, as an instrumentality, yet without him deserving the title of "co-creator".

Only now that the question has been clarified can the Jehovah's Witness way of looking at it be fairly understood. It soon becomes obvious that their understanding is based upon their belief that the one spoken of in John 1:1-3 and Colossians 1:16-20 had a starting point in time, and was the first and only direct creation of the Father. This is proven with this quote from their literature, re. John 1:1:

> "This one was in the beginning with God. Since Jehovah is eternal and
> had no beginning, the Word's being with God 'from the beginning' must
> here refer to the beginning of Jehovah's creative works... Col.
> 1:15... Thus the Scriptures identify the Word (Jesus in his prehuman
> existence) as God's first creation, his firstborn Son...
>
> The Son's share in the creative works, however, did not make him a
> co-Creator with his Father. The power for creation came from God
> through his holy spirit, or active force. And since Jehovah is the source of all life, all animate creation, visible and invisible, owes its life to him. Rather than a co-Creator, then, the Son was the agent or instrumentality through whom Jehovah, the Creator, worked." [*Insight on the Scriptures* Vol.2 p.52, 1988](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002451#h=4-7)

This clarifies another misunderstanding many people have about what Jehovah's Witnesses mean when they say that he is spoken of as "the agent of creation". Their meaning is that Jesus is simply an "instrumentality". Jehovah did all the work, simply using Christ (a bit like how a semi-conductor works? - that's not a JW phrase or idea; neither is the illustration of how a human can act as an instrumentality for a spirit messenger to speak and act; I'm just struggling to distinguish between an agent and an agency. I did look at Vol. 1 under 'Creation' p.527 but that offered no further insight as to the Son being an instrument through whom Jehovah created everything, indirectly.)

**"Why is the word 'other' added?"**  The direct quotes given from their "Insight" book answer the question, from their point of view. It also helps explain why they insert the word 'other' into Colossians 1:16-20 no less than five times. The word is not in the Greek text, and if the translation stuck to "by means of him all things were created" etc. that would leave open the mainstream teaching that Christ was never created. Adding "other" detracts from that while bolstering their teaching that Christ was the first and only direct creation of Jehovah God.

**"What are these 'other' things?"**  It must be repeated again that the NWT does ***not*** add 'other' anywhere in John 1:1-3. But it does in Colossians 1:16-20 and that has been answered: ***all things other than the Word of God himself.*** It does seem surprising, therefore, that adding 'other' to John 1:1-3 was refrained from. Had it done so, there would have been consistency.